# element disappears when it's hovered on

Tags: css, hover, pseudo-element

I have a tip appear via  :hover:before in css. The only problem is, the element being hovered on disappears when you hover on it, although the tip appears. Anyone know what I should adjust, please?

html:

```
<body>
<div class="content">
(...content of page)
</div>
</body>
```

jquery:

```
$('.content').prepend("<div id='arrowdown'><i tip='Return to story' class='fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down fa-2x vidclose'></i></div>");
```

css:

```
.vidclose {
    color: lightgray;
    z-index: 99;
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    right: 37px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.vidclose:hover{
    z-index: 99;
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    right: 37px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #007fd4;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.vidclose:hover:before {
        content: attr(tip);
        margin-right: 35px;
        color: #007fd4;
        font-family: "Muli", sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        position: relative;
        top: -6px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your code a bit and it is working.

**[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GS4GH/)**

```
$('.content').prepend("<div class='arrowdown' tip='Return to story'><i  class='fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down fa-2x vidclose'></i></div>");


.arrowdown {
    color: lightgray;
    z-index: 99;
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    right: 37px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.arrowdown:hover{
    padding: 10px;
    color: #007fd4;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.arrowdown:hover:before {
    content: attr(tip); 
    float:left;
    color: #007fd4;
    font-family: "Muli", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin:7px 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that the arrow is placed on the webpage using

```
.fa-arrow-circle-o-down:before { content: "\f01a"; }
```

What this does is set the element `<i>`'s `:before` pseudo element to the above content.

Now when you hover you change the content of this elements `:before` pseudo element to this:

```
.vidclose:hover:before {
    content: attr(tip);
    margin-right: 35px;
    color: #007fd4;
    font-family: "Muli", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    position: relative;
    top: -6px;
}
```

so what happens is you change the content of your `:before` and remove that arrow.

What your website does for the other elements to combat this issue is set the `:hover:before` to the class `.righticon`

So change your CSS to this and put the `tip` attribute in the `div` for `arrowdown` you should be good to go :

```
.righticon:hover:before {
    content: attr(tip);
    margin-right: 35px;
    color: #007fd4;
    font-family: "Muli", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    position: relative;
    top: -6px;
}
```

Also, don't forget to add the class `righticon` to your `arrowdown` div

Comment: @LauraNMS well then there is something else not working properly. Can you create a fiddle replicating your issue? because I really don't see anything wrong with your above code aside from the redundancy

Comment: It's at http://newsinteractive.post-gazette.com/odysseys/#belarus. Hover over the down arrow in the right corner while the video is playing. Or, when the video is finished playing, click the Replay icon then hover over the down arrow in the right corner.

Comment: #Adjit: The tooltip doesn't appear at all when I do it this way.